# gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported

Tags: cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

```
Your configFile is invalid: /cypress.config.ts

It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /cypress.config.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

in cypress base image im trying to test the login page, im getting the above error.

command: npx cypress run --env tags='@login'

when the command executed cypress.config.ts file is not reading.

is it the file format issue ?

Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that particular error by adding typescript as a dependency in package.json inside of the e2e folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).